# How to upload a file via ftp in PHP?

Tags: php, file, upload, ftp

I have a form with html browse type and a submit button. I chose a file using browse button and submit the form. On form submission following code is called.

```
$conn_id="myid";
$conn_id = ftp_connect ( 'server' );
$ftp_user_name="username";
$ftp_user_pass="password";

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login ( $conn_id , $ftp_user_name , $ftp_user_pass );

// check connection
if ((! $conn_id ) || (! $login_result )) {
    echo "FTP connection has failed!" ;
    exit;

} else {
    echo "Connected to for user $ftp_user_name" ;
} 

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put( $conn_id, "images/signatures/" . $fileName , $_FILES['tmp_name'] , FTP_BINARY );

// check upload status
if(!$upload){
    echo "FTP upload has failed!" ;
} else {
    echo "Successfully Uploaded." ;
}
```

But it produce the following warning:

```
Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/echdp/_ProviderSignature.php on line 70 FTP upload has failed!
```

But when I hard code the source path in above code then it upload the file on server:

```
$upload = ftp_put( $conn_id, "images/signatures/myfile.txt" , "/var/www/images/hello.txt" , FTP_BINARY );
```

Comment: Are you certain that your html form has the attribute `enctype='multipart/form-data'`? Otherwise, the $_FILES array will not be populated and you'll get the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of html code with enctype:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Do you have `enctype` in `Form` tag? Without the attribute your file won't be send.

For debugging of $_FILES array. Try

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

to see if the data are correct.

Your variable:

```
$_FILES['tmp_name']
```

is used wrongly because $_FILES contain files not a one file. Therefore you should write:

```
$_FILES['your-name-in-html-form']['tmp_name'] // your-name-in-html-form = myfile in the example above
```

Have a look on the example: http://www.zymic.com/tutorials/php/creating-a-file-upload-form-with-php/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = '/public_html/dir/dir2/dir3/somefile.txt';
$ftp_server = "yourdomain.in";
$ftp_user_name = "ftpusername";
$ftp_user_pass = "ftppassword";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Your file will be uploaded in the `/public_html/dir/dir2/dir3/` directory of your domain.
Caution: Never upload an index file when you are testing this feature.
Source: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$_FILES['tmp_name']
```

isn't name of your file. It is stored in:

```
$_FILES['inputname']['tmp_name']
```

where inputname is name of your field. Also check your form for enctype ="multipart/form-data".

Be aware of simply putting on your server everything that user can send - if there is access to uploaded files by http (like http://yoursite/images/signatures/uploadedfile.xxx) someone can put .php files on your server and execute it !

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $_FILES['tmp_name'] does not contain the filename. Try `print_r($_FILES)` to see what it contains. Also, use multipart/form-data as your form enctype.