# How to make so people can upload files to my website and display them?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

How to make so people can upload files to my website and display them, for example, I want people to be able to upload books like archive.org. FYI I do not know PHP. Heres my code

```
<html>    
    <head> 

        <title>Book Store</title>  
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo2.ico" />
         <link href = "style1.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />  
    </head>    
    <body> 

    <style>

</style>

</div>


    <h1>Book Store</h1>
     <input type="text" id="booksearch" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for books.."size="40">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="">A</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="alice.epub">Alice and Wonderland</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="">B</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="Bible kjv pdf.html">Bible King James Version</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="">H</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="hunted down.epub">Hunted Down by Charles Dickens</a></li><br> 
  <li><a href="">P</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="Pilgrim progress.html">Pilgrim Progress</a></li>
  <li><a href="Pride and Prejudice.epub">Pride and Prejudice epub</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="">S</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="Sherlock Holmes complete book.epub">Sherlock Holmes complete book epub</a></li>
  <li><a href="cano.pdf">Sherlock Holmes complete book pdf</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="">T</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="Holmes.pdf" download>The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes pdf</a><br></li>
  <li><a href="fatherbrown1.epub">The Innocence of Father Brown book ep 1 epub</a></li>
  <li><a href="fatherbrown2.epub">The Wisdom of Father Brown book ep 2 epub</a></li>
  <li><a href="fatherbrown3.epub">The Incredulity Of Father Brown book ep 3 epub</a></li>
  <li><a href="fatherbrown4.epub">The Scandal Of Father Brown ep 4 epub</a></li>
  <li><a href="fatherbrown5.epub">The Secret Of Father Brown ep  epub</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="">N</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="nontredam.epub">Nontre Dam history</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="">R</a></li><br>
  <li><a href="romeo.epub">Romeo and Juliet</a></li>
</ul>   
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faultexception.reader">Get free epub reader for android</a><br>
<script>
function search() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('booksearch');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>





       <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="600">    





<button onclick="JavaScript:alert('You will love this book!')">
<img src="http://moziru.com/images/book-clipart-cartoon-14.jpg" alt="What We think of this Book" height = "100">
<br>What We think of this Book</button>
<br>
<a href="html.html" atnip construction>Atnip Construction</a><br>
</body>    
</html>
```

Please tell me what I need to add to this code. I don't have any tried version of what I want. If any questions
please ask.

HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Please provide the following information:</h2>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />
Host <br />
<input type="text" name="host" /><p />

Username <br />
<input type="text" name="user" /><p />

Password <br />
<input type="password" name="pass" /><p />

Destination directory <br />
<input type="text" name="dir" /><p />

File <br />
<input type="file" name="file" /><p />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php
// get FTP access parameters
$host = $_POST['host'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$destDir = $_POST['dir'];
$workDir = "/usr/local/temp"; // define this as per local system
// get temporary file name for the uploaded file
$tmpName = basename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
// copy uploaded file into current directory
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $workDir."/".$tmpName) or      die("Cannot move uploaded file to working directory");
// open connection
$conn = ftp_connect($host) or die ("Cannot initiate connection to host");
// send access parameters
ftp_login($conn, $user, $pass) or die("Cannot login");
// perform file upload
$upload = ftp_put($conn, $destDir."/".$_FILES['file']['name'], $workDir."/".$tmpName, FTP_BINARY);
// check upload status
// display message
if (!$upload) {
    echo "Cannot upload";
} else {
    echo "Upload complete";
}
// close the FTP stream
ftp_close($conn);
// delete local copy of uploaded file
unlink($workDir."/".$tmpName) or die("Cannot delete uploaded file from working directory -- manual deletion recommended");
?>
```

Comment: Do you want people to be able to upload files to your server or will you use a cdn or a different server?

Comment: Hopefully to my server but if that is very difficult I could use a CDN.

Comment: Like learning anything with any language, start small. Start with a simple html document that displays a single input text box and one submit button linked to the input text box. Then write a php script for that form that uploads what ever data you input into that form. Then your goin to need to practice implementing security so an A-Hole can't upload anything malicious or XSS-Attack you. Make sure to validate all text input, even file names, via REG-EX, and run a function to make sure the book contains only text.

Comment: There is more to uploading files, than just uploading files. This is especially true on the internet. If you really plan on giving the public WWW access to a personal server, security is crucial, especially if you plan on holding peoples data.

Comment: they can only upload certain file types such as books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and easy solution:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File: <input type="file" name="file"/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $file['size'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];

        $file_ext = explode(".", $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        $allowed = array("epub", "pdf", "html"); //The extensions you allow

        if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
            if ($file_error === 0) {
                if ($file_size <= 2097152) {
                    $file_destination = ' '.$file_name; // If ' ', the file will be placed in this directory
                    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                        echo $file_destination;
                    } else {
                        echo "An error has been encountered while moving your file!";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Your file is too big!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "An error has been encountered while uploading your file!";
            } 
        } else {
            echo "You can't upload files of this type!";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Notes**:
- `$file_destination = ' '.$file_name;` -> The ' ' represents in which directory after this one the file will be place in, so ' ' means that it will be placed in this directory, 'test/' means it will be placed in the `test` subdirectory of this directory, etc.

- If you want something more secure you could try [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)
- You could also look through one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502706/how-to-upload-a-file-via-ftp-in-php) solutions

**I've tried the script above and it seems to move the file but that file actually doesn't exist in that directory.**

So here's an updated script that actually does work:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $host = "ftp.example.com";
        $user = "username";
        $pass = "password";
        $destDir = "/public_html";    //The destination directory for the uploaded file (`/public_html` is the root directory for your website files, in some cases it could also be `/var/www`)
        $workDir = " ";

        $tmpName = basename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $workDir.$tmpName) or die("Cannot move uploaded file to working directory");

        $conn = ftp_connect($host) or die ("Cannot initiate connection to host");
        ftp_login($conn, $user, $pass) or die("Cannot login");
        $upload = ftp_put($conn, $destDir."/".$_FILES['file']['name'], $workDir.$tmpName, FTP_BINARY);
        if (!$upload) {
            echo "Cannot upload\n";
        } else {
            echo "Upload complete\n";
        }
        ftp_close($conn);

        unlink($workDir.$tmpName) or die("Cannot delete uploaded file from working directory -- manual deletion recommended");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Like how do you do that.

Comment: or link to tutorial

Comment: I have linked a tutorial, but do not put the host, username, password and directory fields (define them in the php code that uploads the file) and if you run into any problems than ask here.

Comment: I got error Warning: move_uploaded_file(/usr/local/temp/phpA235.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\dashboard\upload.php on line 11

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp1\tmp\phpA235.tmp' to '/usr/local/temp/phpA235.tmp' in C:\xampp1\htdocs\dashboard\upload.php on line 11
Cannot move uploaded file to working directory

Comment: also what do i define in username and host etc.

Comment: Does that directory exist on your machine? And also you don't have to use that directory, you could use which evere directory you want.

Comment: Where is you website being hosted?

Comment: localhost and I have the directory C:\xampp1\htdocs\dashboard\upload.php but don't know where the other one is

Comment: You can use this directory for the file upload `C:\xampp1\htdocs\dashboard\`. Where is your website going to be hosted in the future? I recommend you to test your website on a free web host like `000webhost` or `IfinityFree` so you don't have to go through the hassle of configuring everything on localhost.

Comment: I set the destination directory for it and got same error

Comment: I did now in the question

Comment: First off I would suggest you test your code on a web host and get the ftp login credentials, and then change the `$workDir` to `$workDir = "/public_html";`. I would like to recommend that you use `000webhost` for this test. You need the ftp credentials in order for this php script to function correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205010/discussion-between-coder-and-leon-kunstek).

Comment: When attempting to recreate the code, I encounter an error message "This page isn’t working". Would you like to provide a tutorial on how to reimplement the code?

Comment: @123456frank I'm guessing the error you're referring to is browser generated, in which case there is likely a problem with your code, I would recommend you turn on error reporting in your script in order to get a more detailed explanation of what actually went wrong.