# How can I restrict minimum 5 files can upload and get error message when wrong format?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I:

- limit the upload files number to 5 with echo error message while trying to upload more.
- restrict total files size to 20 MB
- and get error message when uploading the wrong file format.

```php
     // Count total files
      $countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);


      // Prepared statement
      $query = "INSERT INTO img (name,image,random) VALUES(?,?,'{$_SESSION['random']}')";

      $statement = $conn->prepare($query);

      // Loop all files
      for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){

        // File name
        $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

        // Get extension
        $ext = end((explode(".", $filename)));

        // Valid image extension
        $valid_ext = array("png","jpeg","jpg");

        if(in_array($ext, $valid_ext)){

          // Upload file
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename)){

            // Execute query
            $statement->execute(array($filename,'upload/'.$filename));

          }

        }

      }
         echo "File upload successfully";
    }
```

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516228/how-to-make-so-people-can-upload-files-to-my-website-and-display-them/59516260#59516260.

Comment: @LeonKunštek checked...I am not very handy in php codes....atleast let me know how can I restrict it to 5 files and 20 MB ?

Comment: You can use `$_FILE['size']` to get the size and check if it's `<= 20971520`

Comment: And to get the number of files, you can probably get their ip and keep track of how many files were uploaded from a specific ip.